# Getting an Unexpected remote arg error when trying to run rsync in python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync

I am trying to make an Rsync call in python 3.4 using the `call()` method of the subprocess module and public keys for authentication, so that I can sync a remote folder.  The location of the folder is passed in dynamically via JSON.  The code involved is as follows:

```
response_dict = json.loads(response)
source = 'user@server.example.com:' + response_dict['path'] + '/'
args = ['rsync', '-rv', '-e', '--delete', '--progress', '--update', 'ssh', '-i', '/path/to/public.key', source, '/path/to/local/folder/']
call(args)
```

I've tried several variations of the command, including:

```
args = ['rsync', '-rv', '-e', 'ssh', '-i', '/path/to/public.key', source, '/path/to/local/folder/', '--delete', '--progress', '--update']
```

and

```
args = ['rsync', '-rv', '-e', 'ssh', '-i', '/path/to/public.key', '-l', 'user', source, '/path/to/local/folder/', '--delete', '--progress', '--update']
```

and even

```
args = ['rsync', '-rv', '-e', 'ssh', '-i', '/path/to/public.key', '-l', 'user', 'user@server.example.com:' + response_dict['path'] + '/', '/path/to/local/folder/', '--delete', '--progress', '--update']
```

But I get the same error:

```
Unexpected remote arg: user@server.example.com:/path/to/remote/folder/ 
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1330) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I'm new to python and am pretty much learning as I go along, but this one has me completely stumped.  I've been googling for the whole day and most of yesterday, but every solution to a similar problem I've found has had no effect.  If someone could help me figure out what's going wrong, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the rsync command to work in the shell without Python? If so, what was the command?

Comment: The original command was provided by someone else, and it ran in a bash script. To the best of my knowledge it works. It is: `rsync -rv -e "ssh -i /path/to/public.key" user@server.example.com:/path/to/remote/folder/ /path/to/local/folder/ --delete --progress --update`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should verify that the ssh command works. If it doesn't, then there isn't any point trying to get it to work in Python.

Secondly, the `-e` command should be a single string, e.g.

```
args = ["rsync", "-rv", "-e", "ssh -i /path/to/public.key", "user@server.example.com:/path/to/remote/folder/", "/path/to/local/folder/", "--delete", "--progress" "--update"]
```

Comment: That's champion Alasdair, thanks so much.  I'd seen solutions where some parts of the commands had to be in one string, but I don't think that was one of them.  Incidentally I'd already asked the originator to verify that it was correct just prior to posting but he was taking his sweet time :D  Thanks again

Comment: If you separate it, e.g. `..., "-e", "ssh", "-i", "/path/to/public.key", ..."` then `/path/to/public.key` is treated a separate argument to rsync, rather than part of the value for the `-e` option.